# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given login page

Tags: python, html, django

So I am new to python and I have been trying to make a very basic login page and whenever I look up this error all the solutions are very specific to the persons code. I am learning python for my comsci 3 independent study class and I have been making a very simple website so I don't really know how to fix this. I have been running into a lot of different errors making the front end and back end of a login/logout page. So here is my code thanks for the help:)

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from hello.views import myView
from hello.views import myHome
from hello.views import home
from hello.views import index
from hello.views import game
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
#from hello.views import index
from django.conf.urls import url, include
urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/',include('hello.urls')),
    path('sayHello/', myView),
    path('home/',home,name='Home'),
    path('game/',game),
    path('home/game.html',game),
    path('home/home.html',home),
    path('game/game.html',game),
    path('game/home.html',home),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView, {'template_name': 'logged_out.html'}, name='logout'),

]
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**logged_out.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}See you! {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Logged out</h2>
  <p>You have been successfully logged out.</p>
  <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a> again.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% block title %}Django Simple Login{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Django Simple Login</h1>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      Hi {{ user.username }}!
      <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
    {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
    {% endif %}
  </header>
  <hr>
  <main>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </main>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    <a href="http://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com">simpleisbetterthancomplex.com</a>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `auth_views.LoginView.as_view()` and `auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()` in the `urls.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `LoginView` and `LogoutView` are *class-based views*, you need to use the [**`.as_view()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) to pass these a function that will handle the request:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you as I am new to python I didn't quite realize that class-based views need to call .as_view() method. But I was wondering what exactly is the nature of this error as in why does this error occur so in the future I know what exactly I am looking for when debugging.

Comment: @idianskilz: well if you do not use `.as_view(..)` you will call the `LoginView` *constructor*, and that constructor is not meant to deal with the request (and other parameters).